# GoogleDrive загрузка на UploadURL из браузера

Tags: javascript, браузер, google-drive

Отправляю файл на GoogleDrive из браузера с помощью XMLHttpRequest. Но все заканчивается ошибкой в консоли:

> Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UqhvUIoN.... (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»).

Судя по отправляемым запросам, сама отправка заканчивается успешно. Вот только браузер не хочет обрабатывать ответ...
[image: Запрос OPTIONS заканчивается успешно. В ответе есть заголовки "access-control-"]
Запрос OPTIONS заканчивается успешно. В ответе есть заголовки "access-control-"

[image: А вот запрос PUT уже не обрабатывается javascript, хотя в ответе вернулись корректные данные. Заголовков "access-control-" нет. Очевидно, в этом и есть проблема]
А вот запрос PUT уже не обрабатывается javascript, хотя в ответе вернулись корректные данные. Заголовков "access-control-" нет. Очевидно, в этом и есть проблема.

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

UPD:
Заголовки запроса PUT
[image: Заголовки запроса PUT]

Comment: У вас сайт запущен на localhost:3000?

Comment: Да, тестирую на своей машине

Comment: Кстати, я похожим образом работаю с Яндекс.Диск и Dropbox. С ними проблем нет

Comment: Покажите заголовки запроса для PUT.

Comment: Прикрепил скриншот в основной пост

Comment: Я вручную добавляю только два заголовка: Content-Type и X-Upload-Content-Type. Последний был добавлен исключительно ради эксперимента и будет удален.

Comment: Попробуйте удалить все заголовки, заданные вручную. Если и после этого не получится, то будем думать дальше :)

Comment: Удалил) Но XMLHttpRequest сам добавляет заголовок Content-Type)) Судя по справке, этот заголовок нужно добавлять) https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#example_upload_the_file

Comment: Пока что сделал костыль: если работаю с GoogleDrive и возникает ошибка со статусом 0, реагирую на нее, как на успешное выполнение операции. В принципе, данные из ответа мне и не нужны) Но хочется, конечно, сделать все по человечески)